# Formatting a Jquery AJAX post to send data to WCF service

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf, json

In my service contract I have:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "TreeViewData")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
TreeData[] TreeViewData(string RagId);
```

The Tree data class is simple

```
public interface ITreeDataV1
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string ParentId { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "TreeData", 
Namespace = "http://xxx.com/2011/10/14/TreeDataV1")]
public class TreeData : ITreeDataV1
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ParentId")]
    public string ParentId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And in my service logic itself I have:

```
public TreeData[] TreeViewData(string RagId)
{
// some code and return some array of TreeData           
}
```

My problem is when I create my jquery $.ajax request as:

```
$.ajax(
{
type: "POST", 
url: "http://xxx/Retriever.svc/UI/TreeViewData",  
data: {"RagId":"121"},
dataType: "json",
success: function()
    {
        alert('pop the champagne');
    }
}
);
```

I get the following exception -

> The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The
>   expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can
>   be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the
>   binding.

I'm almost certain the error is in how I formatted the data bit of the request.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire data object needs to be stringified. An easy way to accomplish this is to use the JSON.Stringify method in the JSON2 library. (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Using it would change it to:

```
<script src="JSON2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var myObj = {"RagId":"121"};
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(myObj);
    $.ajax({   
         type: "POST",    
         url: "http://xxx/Retriever.svc/UI/TreeViewData",     
         data: jsondata,   
         dataType: "json",   
         success: function()   
         {   
            alert('pop the champagne');   
         }   
    });  
</script>
```

Doing it manually would look something like:

```
var data = '{"RagID":"121"}';
```

However this approach is inflexible and becomes a time waster when trying to manually stringify complex/dynamic objects.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the contentType in your JQuery ajax request?

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```